# cannot view images in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<section className="slider">
        <ul className="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="5.jpeg" alt=""/>
                <div className="caption center-align">
                    <h2>Take Your Dream Vacation</h2>
                    <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-large">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="2p.jpeg" alt=""/>
                <div className="caption left-align">
                    <h2>We Work With All Budgets</h2>
                    <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-large">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="3p.jpeg" alt=""/>
                <div className="caption right-align">
                    <h2>Group & Individual Getaways</h2>
                    <h5 className="light grey-text text-lighten-3 hide-on-small-only">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam non illo earum cumque id est!</h5>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-large">Learn More</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

I added the materialize css carousel in the JSX, the slider works, but the images are blank, the images don't seem to show on the carousel.

Comment: files not accessible/not served as static/bad url/path..etc... check network request/response

Comment: Your codes are ok, just check the address of images. seems your images URLs don't respond.

Comment: They are static. Meaning they are hard coded.  I don 't seer any errors, so I'm not sure what the problem might be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the src (path) of the images, if they are in the same directory you can change the src to ./[IMG], either if they are in another directory you must set the full path.

For example, if you have this structure :

--src/
  --assets/
    --img/
    --...
  --components/
    --Slider.jsx

You must set as src ./../assets/img/[IMG]

I hope this will help.

Comment: So I did set it to the whole directory path to where the images are ( <img src="/src/components/pages/img/resort1.jpg" alt=""/>) but it still doesn't show. I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: Could you share with us the structure of your project?

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: here is the github repo  https://github.com/shloimimink/custom-pillows.   FYI the images are just a test to see if it works

Comment: You can also : import resort from './img/resort1.jpg; ... <img src={resort} alt=""/>